# ios Facebook SDK Pragma, GCC error

Tags: ios, facebook, pragma

I have to implement a Facebook sharing method... I watched the video, read a couple of tutors, etc... 
1: I registered my app, downloaded the sdk, the samples are running fine
2: when i drag and drop the FacebookSDK.framework into my app (not a new app, it has custom frameworks), and include the #import  into the desired class and the appdelegate, during the build, i keep getting the following error in FBRequest.h:

```
LLVM GCC 4.2 error
'#pragma' is not allowed here

LLVM GCC 4.2 error
instance variable '<unnamed>' has unknown size

LLVM GCC 4.2 error
expected `;' before 'NSError'
```

This is the problematic area

```
@interface FBRequest : NSObject {
 @private
    id<FBRequestDelegate> _delegate;
    NSString*             _url;
    NSURLConnection*      _connection;
    NSMutableData*        _responseText;
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    FBRequestState        _state;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    NSError*              _error;
    BOOL                  _sessionDidExpire;
    id<FBGraphObject>     _graphObject;
}
```

XCode 4.5, trying to run in ios 5.1 simulator and ios6 iPod 4. gen

Thanks

Comment: it would help if you included the actual error/warning/stacktrace that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try switching to Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 instead of LLVM GCC 4.2 in your Project > Build Settings > Build Options > Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C

[image: Build Settings > Build Options > Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C]

p.s. Choose "All" if you don't see "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" there.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was that the main app was using default llvm 4.1, but the framework was still using GCC...